# Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

Im new to data analysis and looking for help.I am creating my Knn algorithm from scratch using python.I think I have a problem with my data(train and test). I think that I have to converted to float but I am not 100% sure. I know  my functions are working, because I tried them with another dataset.

```
from scipy.io import arff
from io import StringIO
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
data_train = scipy.io.arff.loadarff('train.arff')
train = pd.DataFrame(data_train[0])
train.head()
data_test = scipy.io.arff.loadarff('test1.arff') 
print(data_test)
test = pd.DataFrame(data_test[0])
test.head()

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, test, test_size = 0.1, random_state=42)
print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

def distance(testpoint, trainpoint):
    # distance between testpoint and trainpoint.
    dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(testpoint-trainpoint, 2))) 
    return dis

def getNeighbors(X_train, y_train, X_test, k):
        #For each point in X_test, calculate its distance from itself and each point in X_train
        k_neighbors_with_labels = [] # this will be a list (for each test point) of list (contains the tuple (distance,label) of k nearest neighbors). 
        for testpoint in X_test:
            distances_label = [] # this list carries distances between the testpoint and train point
            for (trainpoint,y_train_label) in zip(X_train,y_train):
                # calculate the distance and append it to a distances_label with the associated label.
                distances_label.append((distance(testpoint, trainpoint), y_train_label))
            k_neighbors_with_labels += [sorted(distances_label)[0:k]] # sort the distances and taken the first k neighbors
        return k_neighbors_with_labels
ne = getNeighbors(X_train, y_train, X_test, k = 3)
print(ne)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-3b2868d1fd43> in <module>()
----> 1 ne = getNeighbors(X_train, y_train, X_test, k = 3)
      2 print(ne)

<ipython-input-55-75b4da86d04e> in getNeighbors(X_train, y_train, X_test, k)
      6             for (trainpoint,y_train_label) in zip(X_train,y_train):
      7                 # calculate the distance and append it to a distances_label with the associated label.
----> 8                 distances_label.append((distance(testpoint, trainpoint), y_train_label))
      9             k_neighbors_with_labels += [sorted(distances_label)[0:k]] # sort the distances and taken the first k neighbors
     10         return k_neighbors_with_labels

<ipython-input-42-03d38977fec4> in distance(testpoint, trainpoint)
      1 def distance(testpoint, trainpoint):
      2     # distance between testpoint and trainpoint.
----> 3     dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(testpoint-trainpoint, 2)))
      4     return distance

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: The error _definitely_ indicates that `testpoint` and `trainpoint` are `str`, so you'll need to do some data conversion somewhere.

Comment: my data is an array that contains floats plus another a column called 'CLASS_LABEL' that is an str,it is this one that i need to convert to float?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with your use case to know exactly what you're trying to do, but this code looks like it expects both `testpoint` and `trainpoint` to be single columns of `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment mentions - testpoint and trainpoint appear to be strings.
To confirm this, you might add `print(type(testpoint))` and `print(type(trainpoint))`
to your code to find out what type they actually are.  If they are indeed strings (and the error suggests this); assuming they are numbers stored as stings, then you could simply convert to int or float by doing something like:

```
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(float(testpoint)-float(trainpoint), 2)))
```

replace int with float as required depending on your requirement.

There are a number of ways to tackle this problem, but the fundamental issue is that you cannot use the - operator on strings  - just as the error points out.